# Plotly: adding a shaded threshold to a bar plot

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have a dataset of sales data in a Pandas dataframe `df` that looks similar to the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2021-01-04', '2021-01-05', '2021-01-06', '2021-01-07', '2021-01-08', '2021-01-11', '2021-01-12', '2021-01-13', '2021-01-14', '2021-01-15'],
                  'sales':[1500, 2000, 1300, 2700, 1800, 4500, 2600, 2750, 8000, 1300]})

    date          sales
0   2021-01-04    1500
1   2021-01-05    2000
2   2021-01-06    1300
3   2021-01-07    2700
4   2021-01-08    1800
5   2021-01-11    4500
6   2021-01-12    2600
7   2021-01-13    2750
8   2021-01-14    8000
9   2021-01-15    1300
```

I plot this data, as follows:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.bar(df, x='date', y='sales')
fig.show()
```

[image]

I would like to be able to add some shaded 'thresholds', similar to the following:

[image]

The thresholds are:

- Green:  greater than 5,000
- Yellow: greater than 2,200 and less than 5,000
- Red:  less than 2,200

This would be similar to the `fill_between` method in `Matplotlib`.

Is this possible in Plotly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best is to use [`add_hrect()`](https://plotly.com/python/horizontal-vertical-shapes/#horizontal-and-vertical-lines-and-rectangles) in this case.

```
fig.add_hrect(y0=0, y1=2200, line_width=0, fillcolor="red", opacity=0.25)
fig.add_hrect(y0=2200, y1=5000, line_width=0, fillcolor="yellow", opacity=0.25)
fig.add_hrect(y0=5000, y1=10000, line_width=0, fillcolor="green", opacity=0.25)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this between figure creation and fig.show():

```
fig.add_shape(type="rect", line_width=0,
    xref="x domain",
    x0=0, x1=1, y0=0, y1=2200,
    fillcolor="Red", opacity=0.25,
)
```

This will give you the red rectangle, you can add the other ones accordingly by adjusting fillcolor and opacity as well as y0 and y1 to your needs.

Note how x0 and x1 are given in relative coordinates of zero to one to span the complete figure (because xref="x domain") but y0 and y1 use absolute values.

For further reference, see the [Plotly docs on Shapes](https://plotly.com/python/shapes/).